# Programming with COALESCE function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
ac  asg     asgc    asgdt
1   abc     abc     2012-06-01 00:00:00.000
1   NULL    NULL    2012-06-02 00:00:00.000
1   xyz     xyz     2012-07-01 00:00:00.000
1   NULL    NULL    2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
2   NULL    NULL    2012-07-03 00:00:00.000
2   lmn     lmn     2012-08-01 00:00:00.000
2   NULL    NULL    2012-08-02 00:00:00.000
```

I have to remove nulls by repeating previous text, so I wrote

```
Declare @asgc nvarchar(10)
UPDATE coalescetest 
SET 
    @asgc = COALESCE(asgc, @asgc),
    asgc = COALESCE(asgc, @asgc)
```

This code gave me below output

```
ac  asg     asgc
1   abc     abc
1   NULL    abc
1   xyz     xyz
1   NULL    xyz
2   NULL    xyz
2   lmn     lmn
2   NULL    lmn
```

Problem here is, it should repeat previous text at account level. As it is seen, `'xyx'` value for `ac` 1 is repeated to `ac` 2. This should not happen. Ideal output should be like this

```
ac  asg     asgc
1   abc     abc
1   NULL    abc
1   xyz     xyz
1   NULL    xyz
2   NULL    NULL
2   lmn     lmn
2   NULL    lmn
```

So, I wrote a loop at `ac` level. But it is killing performance. Can anyone please suggenst a way out. Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Tables have *no* inherent order. You're lucky that, with this small sample size, it *happens* to produce updates that are even close to what you want. The first thing we need is a column by which we can *define* an order, by which we can determine which rows come before other ones.

Comment: @Damien Hi, I do have datetime referecne coumn.I updated my example table. My actual table has over millions of records. Before passing data to Coalesce function, I will sort data by datetime column.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use this column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
declare @tab table (ac int not null, asg char(3) null, asgc char(3) null, asgdt datetime not null)
insert into @tab(ac,asg,asgc,asgdt) values
(1,'abc','abc','2012-06-01 00:00:00.000'),
(1,NULL,NULL,'2012-06-02 00:00:00.000'),
(1,'xyz','xyz','2012-07-01 00:00:00.000'),
(1,NULL,NULL,'2012-07-02 00:00:00.000'),
(2,NULL,NULL,'2012-07-03 00:00:00.000'),
(2,'lmn','lmn','2012-08-01 00:00:00.000'),
(2,NULL,NULL,'2012-08-02 00:00:00.000')

update
    t1
set
    asgc = t2.asgc
from
    @tab t1
        inner join
    @tab t2
        on
            t1.ac = t2.ac and   --Belong to same account
            t2.asgc is not null and --Has a useful value
            t2.asgdt < t1.asgdt   --Is an earlier row
        left join
    @tab t3
        on
            t1.ac = t3.ac and   --Belong to same account
            t3.asgc is not null and --Has a useful value
            t3.asgdt < t1.asgdt and   --Is an earlier row
            t3.asgdt > t2.asgdt   --But occurs later than t2
where
    t1.asgc is null and --Needs a fill-in value
    t3.ac is null   --And no better matching row was found for the replacement

select * from @tab
```

Result:

```
ac          asg  asgc MysteriousUnamedColumn
----------- ---- ---- -----------------------
1           abc  abc  2012-06-01 00:00:00.000
1           NULL abc  2012-06-02 00:00:00.000
1           xyz  xyz  2012-07-01 00:00:00.000
1           NULL xyz  2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
2           NULL NULL 2012-07-03 00:00:00.000
2           lmn  lmn  2012-08-01 00:00:00.000
2           NULL lmn  2012-08-02 00:00:00.000
```

Note that, at no point, am I relying on *what* order the `UPDATE` is actually applied to the table.

---

Just realised that my answer, of course, doesn't actually *use* `COALESCE`, as per the title of the question. But, TBH, it was the wrong tool for the job at hand anyway. You could re-write the above query to use a `COALESCE`, and have it update all rows rather than just those with `NULL` values, but I can't think of any sane reason to do so.

Comment: @Demien Thank you so much for the solution. I have to change the title, but leaving it same, so that this post can show an alternate.